# Is it safe to cook pork chops that thawed on counter overnight?

Tags: pork-chops

Is it safe to cook pork that thawed on the counter overnight?

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat, it's actually more of a duplicate of http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/is-there-a-problem-with-defrosting-meat-on-the-counter

Answer (score 1):

No. It has been out in room temperature for far too long to be safe to eat. Pork chops will be completely defrosted after 2-3 hours, which means they have been in the 'danger zone' for 6-8 hours. If you are defrosting over night, I would recommend putting it in a bowl of water in the fridge.

Comment: I don't think there's even any need for the bowl of water.

Comment: @logophobe That might just be because my fridge is somewhat temperamental, and sometimes decides that an appropriate temperature is -4 degrees instead of +4. I've learned that with the bowl of water, my food will defrost anyway :)