# Forgot to Turn on Crock Pot

Tags: roast, crockpot, defrosting

I put a frozen beef roast (about 2 lbs) in the crockpot with some sherry and onions, but forgot to turn the crock pot on.  The lid was on, and when I got home about 6 hours later the roast was still mostly frozen (I could only get a fork into about ¼ to ½ an inch) and the outside of it still felt very cold.  I immediately put the whole crock pot in the fridge and I'm wondering if I can cook the roast today, or if I need to toss it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it was still mostly frozen I think it's just fine and no different than leaving out on the counter to thaw in the morning before going to work.

Comment: Leaving something on the countertop to thaw isn't generally something that we (or food safety agencies) would typically suggest, though. See here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/is-there-a-problem-with-defrosting-meat-on-the-counter