# Pork roast left out

Tags: food-safety

I was defrosting a 4 lb pork roast. I took it out about 10am. I went out that night and came home around 10pm. The roast felt cool to the touch but not really “cold.” I put it in the fridge and this morning i put it in the crock pot but i’m a little worried. It was cryovacked, if that makes any difference. Thoughts? Would you still eat it?

Comment: Please [don’t defrost food on the counter](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/is-there-a-problem-with-defrosting-meat-on-the-counter).

Answer (score -2):

The rule of thumb is 4 hours below 140 F and above 40F is the danger zone.

It it was out for 10 hours then part was probably over 40F for 4 hours.

Comment: And this exactly what the duplicate post is about - only the time frame is [two hours, not four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger_zone_(food_safety)).

Comment: For questions like this that are duplicates of a general canonical, you can just vote to close, and leave any specific advice (like this answer) as a comment.