# How long is bacon that was thawed out at room temperature overnight eatable?

Tags: bacon

How long is bacon that was frozen and thawed out overnight eatable?

Comment: See this question for your answer: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/is-there-a-problem-with-defrosting-meat-on-the-counter or if that doesn’t have your answer, [edit] the question to explain why it isn’t a dupe

Comment: Bacon is a bit of a special case given the very high salt content that would inhibit bacterial growth. But still better safe than sorry.

Comment: @miken32 I’d be a less worried about dry-cured bacon, but that’s also unlikely to be the type in question here. [The USDA chart on bacon](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/food-safety/safe-food-handling-and-preparation/meat/bacon-and-food-safety) does show multi-day room temp storage for dry cure, none at all allowed for generic/common bacon (apparently, even though it’s cured it’s still not sufficiently so to preserve it like a dry cure)