# Chicken defrosted on Saturday can I eat it on Monday

Tags: chicken, meat

I defrosted chicken on Saturday. Can I eat it for lunch on Monday?

Comment: Was this chicken cooked or uncooked?  Was is defrosted in the refrigerator or some other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it dangerous to eat meat which has been left out and then cooked?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/why-is-it-dangerous-to-eat-meat-which-has-been-left-out-and-then-cooked)

Answer (score 1):

If you defrosted it correctly ([How to quickly and safely defrost chicken?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/how-to-quickly-and-safely-defrost-chicken)), then yes. You can cook and serve it 2 (even 3 or 4) days later.

Comment: There is an additional possibility of risk if the chicken was not bought frozen, or was not frozen on the day of purchase.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you cook it properly 165 F according to [foodsafety.org](http://www.foodsafety.gov/keep/charts/mintemp.html) you would have no problems. If you plan to eat it raw or rare, contamination may occur (this doesn't mean it's a Death sentence and you'll get sick for sure, but you have to know your risks)